# Text Box Resizing to Stay within Background Picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Click here for photo of the text overrunning the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBrp0.jpg)I have a text box with a background picture as I resize the picture changes appropriately (using percentages) but the text box overflows. I am using the overflow function in CSS but I need the text box to resize it`s length as it runs out of room so that the picture stays behind. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

P.S. Any more elegant solutions to replace the use of CSS overflow function welcome!

P.P.S. I am currently researching the jquery function "resize" and I think the solution could be in linking the text box to this function.

HTML code is as follows

```
<main id="about">

        <img src="images/Lace Eckhardt 1425.jpg" alt="" id="laceBike">
        <section class="lace">
        <h2>About Lace</h2>
        <div id="aboutText">
            <p>Lace Eckhardt has never done things by halves and her latest venture Sidekicks is certainly no exception. Eckhardt, 31 leads a dynamic life, a self-confessed ‘kidult’ she can be found on her BMX heading for an early morning surf, or practicing her skate tricks on the custom half pipe built in her garden.</p>

<p>Having spent half her life trashing numerous pairs of shoes she started to take the search for sturdy, well-made kicks seriously. “I spent so much time on-line looking for stylish skate shoes but most of what I found were either poorly made or way too commercial. When I did find a style that suited my lifestyle and my taste I’d tell everyone how great they were…then someone suggested I set up a shop. I listened, and the rest is history!” </p>

<p>Starting off with twenty of her top styles, Eckhardt set up a successful eBay shop and is now launching this new site Sidekicks, concentrating predominantly on her six feature shoes. “I have so much faith in the brands and styles I’m selling, as long as I have one of each of them in my wardrobe I honestly don’t need anything else. Although new colours and fabrics are released every season and I’m a sucker for those.” Eckhart has some loyal customers who won’t buy their shoes anywhere else. “One guy in Ecuador bought his first pair from me just a month after I’d set up the eBay store and now owns at least one of each style. He sends me photos of him when he gets a new pair, I love seeing my customers wearing my shoes and doing what they love. It’s like a cool little like-minded community…one of my long standing customers even sent me a skateboard she’d designed, how awesome is that?!’</p>
    </div>
    </section>

</main>
```

Current Relevant CSS

```
 main {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: both;
}

.lace {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(248,246,246,0.50);
    margin-top: -79%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#aboutText {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(75,1,3,1.00);
}
#laceBike {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please show us an example of your issue so we can help you more easily  :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take a tour of the help centre and in particular read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Nice image. Post some code please.

Comment: Hi thanks every one for your comments. I have uploaded an image and some code anything else that I can do to make it easier to understand the problem please tell me and I will post it up. This is my first question on the forum so thanks for your patience.

Comment: I think I have found a solution here http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/ I just have to adapt it to my own code. (easier said than done, lol, working on it now).

Comment: I can`t make it work. I am only just starting to understand jQuery. Another solution is possibly using the .innerHeight on the photo and then modifying the .lace class to keep the innerHeight on the text box always -50px of the image height. I am pretty sure it is possible but my grasp of jQuery is not quite sound enough to make it happen. I am an online student and need to complete this for an assignment (teachers are not very helpful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have found a complete solution by posting the picture as a background image and then using percentages, media queries and overflow: scroll; in CSS.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


@media (max-width: 1500px){
#main {
 background-image: url(images/Unknown.jpeg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 margin-left: auto;
}
#text {
 width: 55%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: 1%;
 float: right;
 overflow: scroll;
 height: 483px;
 background-color: rgba(233,226,227,0.50);
 padding-left: 13px;
 padding-top: 13px;
 padding-right: 13px;
 padding-bottom: 13px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 19px;
}
h1 {
 width: 50%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: 4.5%;
 text-align: center;
 float: right;
}
}

@media (max-width: 980px){
#text {
 height: 300px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 700px){
#text {
 height: 108px;
 font-size: 18px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 470px){
h1 {
 font-size: 20px;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Text Contained To Pic</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<h1>Where is the Picture in the Background?</h1>
<div id="text">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, posse nusquam ne vix, justo sensibus at has. Ius dicat congue doctus id. Vim ornatus antiopam ea, ea sensibus accusamus mediocritatem has. Ne mollis ullamcorper voluptatibus eos, eum choro virtute facilis eu, cum iusto oratio democritum ad. Pri tacimates adolescens ei, eum augue suscipit interesset an.</p>

<p>Mei ea clita nullam, ea nullam deserunt vulputate cum, tale invidunt eam id. Vidisse honestatis ius ad, in duo facilis definitionem, ea nec equidem sanctus petentium. Mea te evertitur consequuntur. Ex his justo dignissim definitionem, est mutat consequat te, ne dicunt prodesset vix. Percipit electram rationibus ius cu, audire dolorum veritus eu eam.</p>

<p>Lorem imperdiet constituto eu est. No usu quis fabulas verterem. Eirmod volumus electram qui id. Porro oratio at pro, illud sententiae omittantur eum ut. An qui vide summo, vis ex animal impetus. Deserunt sensibus definitionem at eam, in nam hinc rebum dolores.</p>

<p>Te omnis denique probatus est, ex pri justo melius incorrupte. Ex posse euripidis has, nec no vidit invenire. Nam cu hinc possit omnium. Ei clita perpetua pertinacia has, ad eum modo saperet appellantur. Assum adipisci in eum, an clita animal vis, vis id postulant consulatu. Pri eu exerci detracto iudicabit.</p>

<p>Te velit posidonium sed, libris postea per ut. Democritum abhorreant appellantur ad nec, periculis torquatos consetetur pro te. Ex vis tritani alterum rationibus. Sea ex feugiat constituto dissentiet. Sapientem voluptatibus ad his, vix cibo accusam ei.</p>

</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is just a random image I pulled in from the web for the example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRXft.jpg)

So if you put all this together you will have a site that contains the text within a background image. I hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: One thing I am unsure of is how to link the image into the stack overflow code so the solution will display fully in the "Run code snippet" function. If any one can explain that then I can display the full explanation here.

Answer (score 0):

use VH or VW units for all sizing of that box AND the font. see example here https://jsfiddle.net/5rkxkq62/

VH or VW units are in range 0-100, and stands for VIEWPORT HEIGHT/WIDTH. If you use only one of units for both sizing (width and height), you can keep the sizing ratio always the same

But I reccomend to copy it and try it in plain html page, because on jsfiddle you cannot work with resizing window well, and also vh and VW units does not have correct behaviour in that output frame.

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet......
</div>
  </div>

.box{width:80vh; height:50vh; position:relative; margin:auto;
background:url("http://marshall.org/wp-content/themes/marshall/img/featured-space-policy.jpg"); background-size:100% auto;}

.text{background: rgba(255,255,255,.3); color:white; font-size:5vh; position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; height:40%; width:calc(100% - 20px);}
```

Comment: Thanks Zorak I will give this a go and get back to you. I haven`t heard of VH or VW units before. I will do some research.

Comment: Hi Zorak this gave me some new insight but it didn`t cover all the bases. For example the large text box was missing so the length wasn`t challenged and although it resizes when the height changes it doesn`t when the width changes. I have come up with a complete solution which I will post below, it is still a little clunky and I am sure there is better but this is the best I have so far created using only html and css.